# Why is 0.5==0.5f is true but 0.1==0.1f is false?

Tags: java, literals

Please look at following two code:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
   System.out.println(0.5==0.5f);
}
```

Output : true

```
 public static void main(String... args)
 {
   System.out.println(0.1==0.1f);
 }
```

Output: false

Why is it happening so?

Comment: floating point literals are double by default

Comment: Hint, what is `0.1` as a `double`? And as a `float`?

Comment: Neither of the two linked questions actually answers the given question, which is why this works fine for `0.5` but not `0.1`. This just has to do with the fact that `0.5` can be correctly represented in both 32 and 64bit IEEE-754 while `0.1` can't.

Comment: @Voo agreed. Now If you were to post that exact comment as an answer (maybe with some println)... (I'm too lazy)

Comment: @Boris Damn I was hoping you would. Done though, no println output but I think that should be reasonably easy to understand.

Comment: because `0.5 = 2^-1`, hence can be represented exactly in binary. `0.1` is not

Answer (score 43):

You are comparing two types of values: double and float.
Think about the limitations of size with inexact numbers.

An example:

Exact values (decimal)

`value1` -> 1/2 with 5 decimals is 0.50000
`value2` -> 1/2 with 10 decimals is 0.5000000000

then

`value1 == value2` -> returns true

Inexact values (decimal)

`value3` -> 1/3 with 5 decimals is 0.33333
`value4` -> 1/3 with 10 decimals is 0.3333333333

then

`value3 == value4` -> returns false because they aren't the same.

0.1 cannot be represent exactly in binary (like 1/3 in decimal) but 0.5 can be.

The binary representation of `0.1d` -> 0.000(1100)1100110011...
The binary representation of `0.5d` -> 0.1

Answer (score 20):

This has to do with the fact that floating point numbers are represented in the form `c*2^q`. `0.5` can be represented as `1*2^-1` while `0.1` is impossible to represent accurately independent of how large you make c and q.

When comparing a float to a double, the float is cast to a double. If the number that is represented is already correctly representable as a float, it will have the same value when cast as a double, but if not, the double will have some extra significant digits and hence will compare non equal.